# Declare IEnumerable<T> variable for use later on

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a LINQ query such as:

```
using(csv.......)
{
    csv.Select(x => new Data() { ID = x[27], Raw = String.Join(",", x) });
}
//Do some stuff

//Now I want to use the result of the query
foreach(var item in ??)
{

}
```

The query returns IEnumerable within my `using` statement but how do I declare and then assign a variable so I can use it later on in a `foreach` statement?

Comment: I assume the query doesn't work anymore once myObject is disposed. Is that right?

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Oh face palm! DOH! DOH! DOH!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the query is `IEnumerable<Data>` which you can declare outside the `using` block. However, from the comments it is obvious that you cannot enumerate after `myObject` has been disposed. If you don't want to pull all elements into a list before leaving the `using` block your only option is to do the enumeration inside the `using` block. Pulling data from a database requires an open connection to that database etc.

```
using(myObject.......) 
{ 
  var query = csv.Select(x => new Data() { ID = x[27], Raw = String.Join(",", x) }); 
  //Do some stuff 

  //Now I want to use the result of the query
  foreach (var item in query)
    ...
}
```

Comment: I orginally tried that before I asked but there was nothing in the variable

Comment: I think you need to do a .ToList() to execute the query.

Comment: @Jon: When you say there's nothing in the variable, do you mean it's null, or that it's just an empty IEnumerable?

Comment: @TerryDonaghe: No, doing the `foreach` will execute the query in a deferred way, and will have the advantage of not pulling all the data into memory at once. Since Jon says he has six to eight million items in the collection, doing ToList would be a big and unnecessary performance hit.

Answer (score 6):

You should take well advantage of `IEnumerable`. The beauty of this is your query is not evaluated until you are need. Once you do a `ToList()` your query is executed fully. It is well suggested to use `IEnumerable` as much as possible.

You just can define `IEnumerable<Data>` in the outer scope like this

```
IEnumerable<Data> myDataList;
using(myObject.......)
{
    myDataList =csv.Select(x => new Data() { ID = x[27], Raw = String.Join(",", x) });
}
// do your stuffs
// and just use the IEnumerable<Data> in your foreach loop
foreach(var item in myDataList)
{
    // here item is typeof(Data)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable outside the using block.

Call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to execute the query.

```
List<Data> data=null;
using(myObject.......)
{
    data=csv.Select(x => new Data() { ID = x[27], Raw = String.Join(",", x) }).ToList();
}
```

If it's possible to execute the query after returning from the `using` clause you could do:

```
IEnumerable<Data> data=null;
using(myObject.......)
{
    data=csv.Select(x => new Data() { ID = x[27], Raw = String.Join(",", x) });
}
```

But if that's the case, why are you putting it into the `using` clause in the first place?

If the query depends on `myObject` not being disposed you have two choices:

- Use `ToList()` to execute the query immediately and load it all into memory.
- dispose `myObject` later.

Comment: Does calling ToList() have the same performance hit as foreach? The reason I ask is because the IEnumerable<T> has 6-8 million items in it

Comment: To list will load all items into memory.

Comment: But the foreach wont? I can't have that much in memory!